# mageplaza magento-2-social-login: social login don't ppear in the sign up popup

Tags: magento2, extensions, magento-social

I installed  mageplaza magento-2-social-login and i configured both API facebook and API linkdin but when i click in sign in i just got a popup with email and password what is the problem. any help please[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSRsu.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to `Stores > Configuration > Mageplaza extensions > Social Login > General` and then select `Social Popup Login` in multi select configuration field - **Show Social Login Buttons on**

Comment: Popup display on all pages. I just want to display on home page.

Answer (score 0):

**@Pratik Mehta** If you want to display popup only in homepage then you need to make call by class_name or ID.

ID / Class_name mustbe only in homepage.